# How to implement the Sensor Manager on a ViewSonic Tablet?

Tags: android, tablet, android-sensors

I have recently acquired a ViewSonic G Tablet running Android 2.2 for the development of applications.

I have a few applications that use the Sensor Manager to read the orientation values of the phone. I have tested these applications on a few different android phones and they work fine (the sensors are found and the values are output).

However, when I test the applications on the G Tablet, no Orientation sensor is found?? I have no idea why this might be happening, and I was wondering if anyone has any clue what would cause this?

By the way, the tablet has a few other pre-installed applications that use the sensors and they work fine!?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orientation requires both accelerometer and magnetometer combines both sensors to give an up/down and lateral orientation. Perhaps your tablet only has an accelerometer. This should be sufficient for determining which way is up/down, you should access the accelerometer directly.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I would have never thought to just use the Accelerometer.
It works perfectly!

As a side question: Does every Android phone/tablet come with an Accelerometer? If not, is there a way for me to stop people from downloading my application if they don't have one?

Comment: [<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#sensor-hw-features)